# Quotient Ring with kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm new to ring in Abstract Algebra, and I just came across a theorem related to quotient ring and it kind of confused me.

The theorem: **Let I be an ideal of R. The map φ: R → R/I defined by φ(r) = r + I is a ring homomorphism of R onto R/I with kernel I.**

Not sure how to interpret this theorem.

The first way that I interpreted it:
*Does this mean that we can only form a quotient ring if we have an Ideal with kernel?* Which means that R/I exists only if it is kernel I.

Second interpretation:
*It means that if we define a map φ: R → R/I and we want it to be a ring homomorphism, we need to have an Ideal with kernel?*

Sorry for the question, but I don't know anybody that can answer my question.

Thank you,

Comment: It says that every ideal can be realized as kernel of a suitable ring homomorphism.
Note that also the converse is true, namely that the kernel of any ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ is an ideal of $R$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism).

Comment: You might benefit from an example.  Let $R = \Bbb{Z}$, the integers, $I = 6\Bbb{Z}$, the integers that are multiples of $6$.  Then, using the division algorithm (which is not available in all rings), we can write any element of $R$ as $6q+b$ with $0 \leq b < 6$, that is, as a member of $I+b$.  Then $R/I$ is the collection of these remainders module $6$ with the addition and multiplication they inherit from their elements in the ring $R$.  (cont.)

Comment: ...  Then we can read: if you start with a ring, $R$, and one of its ideals, $I$, you can make the quotient ring of remainders modulo $I$, realized (for example) as a homomorphism $\varphi: R \rightarrow R/I$.  It will be the case that the kernel of $\varphi$ (the set of elements of $R$ that are sent to the remainder $0$ in $R/I$ are the elements of $I$.  (This should be clear: the only elements of $\Bbb{Z}$ with remainder $0$ on division by $6$ are multiples of $6$, so it is exactly the subset $I$ that is sent to zero in the quotient.

Comment: Neither of your interpretations accurately reflects what the theorem says. In both cases you are engaging in logical fallacies. The theorem says that if you have an ideal, then the map from $R$ to $R/I$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I$. The theorem already assumes that $R/I$ is a ring. It does not say that if the map is a homomorphism then $I$ is an ideal; that's affirming the consequent (theorem says: if $I$ is an ideal then $f$ is a homomorphism); and it does not say you can only form the quotient if you have an ideal, because the theorem is about the homomorphism, not the quotient.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I now think that I understand more clearly this theorem and quotient ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this theorem is interpreted is that, for any ideal $I$ of the ring $R$, you can form a homomorphism from $R$ to $R/I$ by sending an element $x\in R$ to the coset $x+I$ in $R/I$. The kernel of the homomorphism is $I$.

Neither of your remarks are really related to the theorem, although they do have some meaning. First of all, notice that a quotient ring $R/I$ is *defined* by $I$ being an ideal. So for any ideal $I$ of $R$, you can form a quotient ring, and that construction/definition has nothing to do with this theorem. (You would need the definition of $R/I$ before stating this theorem). A quotient ring a priori has nothing to do with a homomorphism or a kernel, so your statement "$R/I$ exists iff $I$ is kernel" has no meaning.

Another thing to note is that the kernel of a homomorphism *is* always an ideal, which is a good exercise. However, you can have a homomorphism $R\to R/I$ that doesn't have a kernel of $I$.